# WiX Burn silent sql server installation - how to get sql setup progress

Tags: c#, sql-server, installation, wix

I'm deploying sql server express with my custom setup using the WiX Toolset. Is it possible to get the progress percentage out of the silent sql server installation, so I can show it in my own UI?

I tried activating the parameter /INDICATEPROGRESS, but I wasn't able to get the console output via the `Process` class in C#. Furthermore I looked in most of the log files generated by the sql server setup, but I didn't found something giving me info about the progress.

I know there's a /QS parameter, which shows the native sql server express setup dialog in a mode, where no input is allowed, but we don't wanna use this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which is ok for me:

If sql server setup is installing in background, i'm looking for the "Detail.txt" log file which gets generated by the sql server setup. In this log file the setup writes every action which is started running, action by action. So I look every 10 seconds if a particular action has been started, if yes, I set the appropriate progress percentage.